# How to do sub-query correctly while selecting two tables in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

I need to do a sub-query from a table to find all employees working in the same department that is part of the same city, but I'm not getting it.

I have the following tables:

**Table departments**

```
DEPARTMENTS

department_id
department_name
location_id
```

**Table locations**

```
LOCATIONS

location_id
street_address
postal_code
city
state_province
country_id
```

**Table employees**

```
EMPLOYEES

employee_id
first_name
last_name
email
phone_number
hire_date
job_id
department_id
```

My code right now is something like that :

```
SELECT
    firt_name,
    department_id,
    job_id
FROM employees
WHERE state_province = (SELECT state_province FROM locations
                        WHERE state_province = 'Sao Paulo');
```

The problem is that while I want to select `state_province` from the table `locations`, I can't select the name, department id and job id from the table `employees`. How can I select both tables while doing the sub-query ?

Anyway, sorry if I did something wrong in the code, I am new to sub-queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try doing a join between the two tables instead:

```
SELECT
    e.firt_name,
    e.department_id,
    e.job_id,
    l.*             -- replace with columns you really want
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN locations l
    ON e.state_province = l.state_province
WHERE
    e.state_province = 'Sao Paulo';
```

I don't know which columns you want to select from `locations`, but it doesn't really make sense to do a join just for `state_province` alone, as the `employees` table already has this column.  So I just included `location.*` as a placeholder which you can replace with the columns you actually want.

**Edit:**

A join is the way to go here IMO, but if you absolutely need to use a subquery, then you can move your current subquery from the `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    firt_name,
    department_id,
    job_id,
    (SELECT l.state_province FROM locations l
     WHERE e.state_province = l.state_province) state_province
FROM employees e;
```

Note that this will only work if there is one matching province.  For this and performance reasons, my join query is probably what you would want to use in practice.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that I can only do with sub-query. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Monteiro Updated to give you a subquery option.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case, sub-query may not be necessary.
A join table can do the trick.

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.department_id, e.job_id, l.state_province 
FROM employees e 
 LEFT JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id 
 LEFT JOIN locations l ON d.location_id = l.location_id 
WHERE l.state_province = 'Sao Paulo';
```